# Meaning of @ in octave forge function reference

Tags: octave

I'm using some packages from from [Octave Forge](https://octave.sourceforge.io/control/overview.html). In the API documentation some of the functions are prefixed with `@<AnOtherName>/..`

As Example:

```
@lti/c2d
```

What is the meaning of this prefix with @ and the additional name? What is the difference to "normal" functions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`lti` is a class, `@lti/c2d` refers to the `c2d` method of the `lti` class.

In old-style class definitions, class methods for a class `lti` are M-files in a directory called `@lti`, so the `c2d` method would be defined in a file `@lti/c2d.m`.

New-style class definitions use a single `classdef` file to define all methods, but it is still possible to override functions for a specific class or type by creating M-files in a directory `@<class>`. For example, you can create an M-file `@double/foo.m` to create a function `foo` that exists only on inputs of type `double`.